# I2C — set int pin

Tags: i2c

I am using a [blend micro board](http://redbearlab.com/blendmicro/), where the digital pins 4, 6 and 7 are reserved.

I have connected a MPU6050 which uses the I2C protocol, so there is the need for the i2cdev lib to handle that.

The example I am using tells me to use pin 7 as int pin for the mpu6050, but that is not possible, since it is reserved.

Does anybody know how I could set this Pin to some other?

Thanks in Ahead!

Comment: Could you link to your example? The only other hardware interrupt pins on the ATMega32u4 are 0,1,2 and 3 (RX, TX, SDA SCL). So 2 and 3 are not available. That leaves 0, and 1, unless you are using serial for some other module. But maybe the example doesn't necessarily need a hardware interrupt pin at all.

Comment: All I want to setup is based on this project https://edtracker.org.uk/index.php

Comment: this is the very template I am using https://github.com/brumster/EDTracker2/blob/master/EDTracker2_6050/EDTracker2_6050/EDTracker2_6050.ino

Comment: board setup here: https://edtracker.org.uk/index.php/diy/build-it/breadboard

Comment: You need to change the code in that project. Change `INT6` to e.g. `INT2` if you  are using pin 0 instead.

Comment: @Gerben Could you please drop a line of code that shows that? I guess that is what I am looking for…

Comment: Change `EIMSK &= ~(1 << INT6);`, `EIMSK |= (1 << INT6);`, and `ISR(INT6_vect) {` from 6 to 2.